# Redmine Proxy redirection Issue

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, redmine

I have tried to proxy the redmine server from my apache:

```
Proxypass /redmine https://ip
ProxyReverse /redmine https://ip
```

But I'm getting the error from redmine server side as:

```
App 23150 output: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
App 23150 output: Current user: anonymous
App 23150 output: Redirected to https:ip/login?back_url=https%3A%2F%2F10.210.96.100%2F
App 23150 output: Filter chain halted as :check_if_login_required rendered or redirected
App 23150 output: Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)**
```

Please help to resolve this issue.